Tabulator Sorting on multiple column sort with numbers via button
I'm facing a weird issue while implementing a sorting button for my tabulator table:
Tabulator table:
var kalkulationTable = new Tabulator("#KalkulationTable", {
        height: 600,
        ajaxURL: "{% url 'getAngebotskalkulation' pk=object.id%}",
        ajaxConfig: "GET",
        ajaxResponse: function (url, params, response) {
            // Extract only the kalkulation object:
            var kalkulation = response.kalkulation;
            // Return the extracted object for Tabulator
            return kalkulation;
        },
        movableRows: true,
        movableRowsReceiver: "add",
        initialSort: [
            { column: 'titel', dir: 'asc' },
            { column: 'position', dir: 'asc' },
            { column: 'unterposition', dir: 'asc' },
        ],
        placeholder: "Noch keine Kalkulation vorhanden.",
        layout: "fitColumns",
        columns: [
            { title: "T", field: "titel", sorter: "number", frozen: true, maxWidth: 70, editor: "input", },
            { title: "P", field: "position", sorter: "number", frozen: true, maxWidth: 60, editor: "input", },
            { title: "U", field: "unterposition", sorter: "number", frozen: true, maxWidth: 60, editor: "input", },
            { title: "Titeltext", field: "titeltext", sorter: "string", resizable: true, editor: "input", },
            // more columns, which should not matter ...
        ]
    });

Function to sort:
    document.getElementById("sortieren").addEventListener("click", function () {
        kalkulationTable.setSort([
            { column : "titel", dir : "asc" },
            { column : "position", dir : "asc" },
            { column : "unterposition", dir : "asc" },
        ]);
    });

The user wants to use a button to sort the table by titel, position and unterposition like in a 3 level numeric heading system, e.g.



titel
position
unterposition
text




00
00
00
text 1


01
01
01
text 2


01
02
01
text 3


01
02
02
text 3


02
01
01
text 5


02
02
01
text 6



The sorting currently works neither on the initial sort, nor on the button click. Hence i believe the sorting list is wrong. I've checked with the documentation and tried several variants, but i can't find a solution that is working.
However the sorting works by shift+clicking on the sorter in the header, in reverse order (unterposition, position, titel), so i guess the table itself is not the problem.
Can someone please explain to me what is wrong with the sorting list?

Try adding sortOrderReverse: true to your table options.

This works, thank you so much!  Could you briefly explain why? I thought, that would just reverse how the default sort is listed? Then i would write an official answer for persons looking at this.

Sorting in Tabulator works a bit differently that you would expect.  When you specify the sort order as [{ column : "titel", dir : "asc" }, { column : "position", dir : "asc" }, { column : "unterposition", dir : "asc" }], table is sorted by titel first, then the result of that is sorted by position and then the result of that is sorted by unterposition.  Using sortOrderReverse: true reverses this order for arguably a more logical sort order, similar to Excel for example.

As pointed out by helpful @timur in direct comments, my problem is a misconception with the way Tabulator sorts data by default. It does not just continue sorting by every column specified retaining the sort order from the first column, but overrides this with the sorting from the following columns.
To solve the problem, just set option sortOrderReverse: true in the definition of the table, e.g:
var kalkulationTable = new Tabulator("#KalkulationTable", {
        // previous config,
        
        sortOrderReverse: true,
        
        initialSort: [
            { column: 'titel', dir: 'asc' },
            { column: 'position', dir: 'asc' },
            { column: 'unterposition', dir: 'asc' },
        ],
        columns: 
            // column definitions
        ]
    });

